# Flash Video playing outside the defined area

Tags: flash

how do you create the example like "Ninja unboxed 2".
the flash video seems to take over the whole browser window.
or even better as the example above has been removed
http://www.youtube.com/desperados
thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

it's a special advertising they've set up with youtube. in fact the entire page is a SWF mocked up to look like a YouTube page (right click over the suggested videos on the right and you'll see what i mean). after that, you can do what you like